# Python regular expressions, how to match letters that do not belong to an alphabet

Tags: python, regex

Assume that `alphabet` is a list of characters. I want to delete all characters from a string that don't belong to `alphabet`. Thus, how to match all these characters?

EDIT: `alphabet` can have any characters, not necessary letters.

EDIT 2: just curious, is it possible to do with regexp?

Comment: Umm... so what do you want to delete?

Answer (score 1):

Use the string library. Here I use string.ascii_letters, you can also add the digits. In this case the valid characters are:  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789' plus some extra if needed: "-_.()"

```
import string
def valid_name(input):
    valid_chars = "-_.() "+string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(c for c in input if c in valid_chars)
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need Regex for this.  All you need is:

```
# "alphabet" can be any string or list of any characters
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 
            'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 
            'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

# "oldstr" is your old string
newstr = ''.join([c for c in oldstr if c not in alphabet])
```

In the end, `newstr` will be a new string containing only the characters of `oldstr` that were not in `alphabet`.  Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 
...             'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 
...             'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>> oldstr = 'abc123'
>>> newstr = ''.join([c for c in oldstr if c not in alphabet])
>>> newstr
'123'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to go with Regex:**

Use this regex: [^a-zA-Z]

That will match all non letters. Be warned, that will also match whitespace. To avoid that, use [a-zA-Z\s] instead.

**Easier Method:**

You don't actually need regex to do this at all. Simply make a string with the accepted characters and filter out all the characters in your string that aren't in the accepted characters. For example:

```
import string #allows you to get a string of all letters easily

your_word = "hello123 this is a test!!!"
accepted_characters = string.lowercase + string.uppercase + " " #you need the whitespace at the end so it doesn't remove spaces
new_word = ""
for letter in your_word:
    if letter in accepted_characters:
        new_word += letter
```

That would give you "hello this is a test"

**Super Short Method:**

This method isn't the most readable but it can be done in just one line. It's essentially the same as the above method but makes use of [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the `join` method to turn the generated list into a string.

`''.join([letter for letter in your_word if letter in (string.lowercase + string.uppercase + " ")])`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regular expressions, here is a solution that uses `str.translate()`:

```
import string

def delete_chars_not_in_alphabet(s, alphabet=string.letters):
    all_chars = string.maketrans('', '')
    all_except_alphabet = all_chars.translate(None, alphabet)
    return s.translate(None, all_except_alphabet)
```

Examples:

```
>>> delete_chars_not_in_alphabet('<Hello World!>')
'HelloWorld'
>>> delete_chars_not_in_alphabet('foo bar baz', 'abo ')
'oo ba ba'
```

Note that if you are repeatedly calling this with the same alphabet you should construct `all_except_alphabet` outside of the function (and only once) to make this more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Check out re.sub, and use a negated character class like '[^a-d]*' or '[^abcd]*'.
http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html